# Managing PySpark DataFrames

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark

I was successfully able to write a small script using PySpark to retrieve and organize data from a large .xml file. Being new to using PySpark, I am wondering if there is any better way to write the following code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

### xml file from https://wit3.fbk.eu/
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = sc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","transcription").load('ted_en-20160408.xml')
df_values = df.select("seekvideo._VALUE")
df_id = df.select("seekvideo._id")
df_values = df_values.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df_id = df_id.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
result = df_values.join(df_id, "id", "outer").drop("id")
answer = result.toPandas()

transcription = dict()
for talk in range(len(ted)):
    if not answer._id.iloc[talk]:
        continue
    transcription[talk] = zip(answer._id.iloc[talk], answer._VALUE.iloc[talk])
```

where `df` is of the form:

```
DataFrame[_corrupt_record: string, seekvideo: array<struct<_VALUE:string,_id:bigint>>]
```

and `transcription` is a dictionary of the transcriptions of each TED Talk keyed by position. For example, `transcription[0]` is of the form:

```
[(800, u'When I moved to Harare in 1985,'),
 (4120,
  u"social justice was at the core of Zimbabwe's national health policy."),
 (8920, u'The new government emerged from a long war of independence'),
 (12640, u'and immediately proclaimed a socialist agenda:'),
 (15480, u'health care services, primary education'),
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Formatting

Pyspark code can create some pretty long lines, parentheses can allow you to break them up for easier readability. Let's do that first:

```py
### xml file from https://wit3.fbk.eu/
sc = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = (
    sc 
    .read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag","transcription")
    .load('ted_en-20160408.xml')
)

df_values = df.select("seekvideo._VALUE")
df_id = df.select("seekvideo._id")

df_values = df_values.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df_id = df_id.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

result = df_values.join(df_id, "id", "outer").drop("id")
answer = result.toPandas()
```

## withColumn

Sometimes you can swap out `withColumn` to a `select` via `alias`:

```py
df_values = df.select(
    "seekvideo._VALUE",
    monotonically_increasing_id().alias('id')
)

df_id = df.select(
    "seekvideo._id",
    monotonically_increasing_id().alias('id')
)

result = (
    df_values
    .join(df_id, "id", "outer")
    .drop("id")
)
```

## Do you need a join?

You already have these records tied together. This really could be just a select and collect:

```py
result = (
    df
    .select(
        'seekvideo.*', 
        monotonically_increasing_id().alias('id')
    )
)

values = {
    row.id: (row._id, row._VALUE)
    for row in result.collect()
}
```